# How to Apply a Customized Editor Template for View Model in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have what I think is a easy problem but for the life of me I cant figure it out.  I have a form which imports many emails from a multi-line text box.  From that import, I generate a report that tells the user the status of the imported emails and any errors. I can generate the report data fine, but cant seem to display the "Errors" field properly in the view.  The problem appears to be, the editor template for the "Errors" field, is not being used. My question is, how do I get the view to use and render the editor template for the "Errors" field.  I have tried using UIHint, but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

ViewModels.cs

```
//**************************Report View Models***************************************
public class ShowErrors
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
}


public class ReportViewModel
{
    public int TotalEmails { get; set; }
    public int SuccessEmails { get; set; }
    public int DuplicateEmails { get; set; }
    public int InvalidEmails { get; set; }

    [UIHint("ShowErrors")]
    public virtual ICollection<ShowErrors> Errors { get; set; }
}

public static class ViewModelHelpers
{
    //*************************ReportViewModel Helpers**************************************
    public static ShowErrors ShowErrors_ViewModel_To_Domain(this ShowErrors item)
    {
        var showErrors = new ShowErrors
        {
            EmailAddress = item.EmailAddress,
            ErrorDescription = item.ErrorDescription

        };
        return (showErrors);
    }
}
```

Controller for the Report:(Dont think the problem is here, I can generate the data for the report, just cant display it properly.

```
    public ActionResult Import_Report(EmailEditViewModel emailEditViewModel)
        {
            string emailAddress = null;
            string[] emailArray = Request.Form["ImportEmails"].Split (new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            var entityModified = new EmailContact();
            var reportViewModel = new ReportViewModel();
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$"); //Regular Expression that checks email address is valid

            List<ShowErrors> errorList = new List<ShowErrors>();

            foreach (string item in emailArray)
            {
                ShowErrors errorItem = new ShowErrors();
                emailAddress = item.Trim();
                reportViewModel.TotalEmails += 1;

                Match match = regex.Match(emailAddress);  //Check email is in valid format
                if (emailAddress == null || emailAddress == "")
                {
                    reportViewModel.TotalEmails -= 1;
                }
                else if (!match.Success)
                {
                    //Log this email as duplicate
                    reportViewModel.InvalidEmails += 1;
                    errorItem.EmailAddress = emailAddress;
                    errorItem.ErrorDescription = "Invalid Email";
                    errorList.Add(errorItem);
                }
                else if (_globalClasses.IsDuplicateEmail(emailAddress) > 0)
                 {
                     //Log this email as duplicate
                     reportViewModel.DuplicateEmails += 1;
                     errorItem.EmailAddress = emailAddress;
                     errorItem.ErrorDescription = "Duplicate Email";
                     errorList.Add(errorItem);
                 }
                else
                 {
                     entityModified.EmailAddress = emailAddress;
                     entityModified.ActiveCampaigns = entityModified.Campaigns.Count();  //Calculates how many campaigns a contact is a member
                     try
                     {
                         db.EmailContacts.Add(_crypto.EncryptAndSanitizeEmailContacts(entityModified));
                         db.SaveChanges();
                         reportViewModel.SuccessEmails += 1;
                         AddOrUpdateEmailContacts(entityModified, emailEditViewModel.Campaigns); //Saves campaigns selected to this contact
                         db.SaveChanges();
                         //return RedirectToAction("Contact_List");
                     }
                     catch  { }
                 }
            }

            reportViewModel.Errors = errorList;
            return View(reportViewModel);
        }
```

Here is the View:

```
@model HoltsCA.ViewModels.ReportViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Import_Report";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutDashboard.cshtml";

}

<fieldset>
    <legend></legend>
    <div class="row col-md-6">
        <div id="bootstrapTableHeader" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h2 style="text-align:center; color:#fff; font-size:1.3em;">Import Contacts Report</h2>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="bootstrapTableRow" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-7" style="text-align:right">Total Emails:</div>
            <div class="col-sm-5" style="text-align:left">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TotalEmails)</div>
        </div>
        <div id="bootstrapTableRow" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-7" style="text-align:right">Success Imported Emails:</div>
            <div class="col-sm-5" style="text-align:left">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SuccessEmails)</div>
        </div>

        <div id="bootstrapTableRow" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-7" style="text-align:right">Duplicate Emails:</div>
            <div class="col-sm-5" style="text-align:left">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DuplicateEmails)</div>
        </div>

        <div id="bootstrapTableRow" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-7" style="text-align:right">Invalid Emails:</div>
            <div class="col-sm-5" style="text-align:left">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.InvalidEmails)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="height:50px"></div>
        <div id="bootstrapTableHeader" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h2 style="text-align:center; color:#fff; font-size:1.3em;">Error Report</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bootstrapAccentRow" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:left">
                <b>Email Address</b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:left">
                <b>Error Description</b>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bootstrapRow" class="row">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Errors)
        </div>
    </div>

</fieldset>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Finally Here is the Editor Template ShowErrors.cshtml

```
@model ShowErrors
@using HoltsCA.ViewModels

<fieldset>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align:left;">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align:left;">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ErrorDescription)
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to display errors by using editor template. Put your error template inside DisplayTemplates folder under Shared folder.

If you are using `@Html.DisplayFor` then your template should be in the DisplayTemplates folder and similar logic while displaying editing template. To specify which template to use you can also do

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Errors, "ShowErrors")
```

Another thing is your model.Errors is a `List<ShowErrors>` and inside your display template you have just `@model ShowErrors` instead you should display it like `IEnumerable<ShowErrors>` and iterate in the template to show all the errors.

```
@model IEnumerable<ShowErrors>
@using HoltsCA.ViewModels

@foreach(var error in Model)
{
        <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align:left;">
            @Html.DisplayFor(error => error.EmailAddress)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align:left;">
            @Html.DisplayFor(error => error.ErrorDescription)
        </div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I made the corrections you suggested but now receiving this error msg: Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<HoltsCA.ViewModels.ShowErrors>' does not contain a definition for 'EmailAddress' and no extension method 'EmailAddress' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<HoltsCA.ViewModels.ShowErrors>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Tired both IEnumerable<ShowErrors> and List<ShowErrors>

Comment: change the model.EmailAddress to error.EmailAddress and try again

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm missing something. The only place I see to change model.EmailAddress to error.EmailAddress is the display model.  I have done that  but I'm still getting the same error message. Good news is it now see's the display model but cant find a definition for IEnumerable<ShowErrors> nor List<ShowErrors>. Could be please be more specific about what I'm doing wrong?  I think the problem may lie in my ShowErrors_ViewModel_To_Domain ViewModel helper.  But not sure.  I have tried several things but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an `EditorTemplate`, it's a `DisplayTemplate`.

You just need to create a folder named "DisplayTemplates" under `Views/Shared`, and put the `ShowErrors.cshtml` partial view in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is a `List<ShowErrors>` **not** a `ShowError` object.

You could change your view to this:

```
@model List<ShowErrors>
@using HoltsCA.ViewModels

    @foreach(var error in Model)
    {
    <fieldset>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align:left;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(error => error .EmailAddress)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align:left;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(error  => error .ErrorDescription)
            </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I made the corrections you suggested but now receiving this error msg:  Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HoltsCA.ViewModels.ShowErrors>' does not contain a definition for 'EmailAddress' and no extension method 'EmailAddress' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HoltsCA.ViewModels.ShowErrors>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  It seems not to know any longer how to reference EmailAddress and ErrorDescription. Any Ideas?  I appreciate the help.